# Adapt variable arguments in Java to fixed argument in Java

Tags: java, arrays, overloading, variadic-functions, dynamic-dispatch

I have an adapte, aiming to transforme the invocation of the variable argument to a specified method target. The sample code is shown below.

```
class Adapter {

   public Object execute(Object... args){
        run(args);
        //run2(args[0], args[1]);
        //run3(args[0], args[1]);
    }


    private int run(int c, int d){
        return c+d;
    }
    private int run(int a, float b){
        return 0;
    }

    private String run(Integer a, String b){
        return "ss";
    }
    private Object run(Object c, float m, int q){
        return new Object();
    }
    ..........
}
```

The method *execute*() accepts an variable arguments. Based on the element in the *args*, Adapter will choose one of *runX* function with consistent methodtype for execution. For example, run1 will selected if first two element in args are both int. The matching rule is:

```
args:{1,2}   => run(int, int)
args:{new Integer(3), "asdas"}  => run(Integer, String)
args:{new Object(), 4.0, 5}     => run(Object, float, int)
.......
```

Is there a good way to do this invocation transformation in the method *execute*? In Java, the variable *args* and *Array* are identical. It is impossible to iterate each element in the args to find the matched method *run*, due to too large combination space.

---

The requirement comes for an API which accepts variable argument, saying:

```
     Object execute(Object... args)
```

Then I provided some optimized versions of the implementation for many specified kind cases when the element classes in the args.

Comment: but how would it know which method you want??

Comment: This feels like a terrible design. Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: If you want named parameters, switch to objective C, or pass a hash map.   Overloading like how you want is asking for trouble.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to implement "dynamic dispatch" or "multiple dispatch". There are many ways to optimize this, each with its drawbacks and advantages. If I were you I'd start to make it work using an exhaustive search, write a good set of test cases, and the. Try to optimize it using various tree structures, indirection tables, etc

Comment: Why? The Java language (compiler) will select the appropriate method for you. It's called [method overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html). You just have to make them all public with the same name.

Comment: @Andreas, Actually, the method runX are all generated generated, but the invocation exception were riased when invocation. See above..

Comment: @Andreas, look at the code again.  The *compiler* does not know the type of the arguments. It can't choose among overloaded methods, which are compile-time constructs as you say. If all the arguments extended a class or implemented an interface with an identical method, then Java could invoke different methods for different objects without knowing their type, but it can't help with overloading without knowing types at compile time.

Comment: @arcy But compiler would know arguments when writing `execute(1,1)` and select a `execute(int, int)` method. Since we didn't know how execute is called, that might have been the right solution.

Comment: @shijiexu See above where? I see nothing about "generated" or "invocation exception" anywhere.

Comment: FYI: 3rd example won't work, because `4.0` is a `double`, which is not compatible with a `float`, at least not according to Java coercion rules.

Comment: @Andreas. Thanks. The error i talked was from other place at runtime. I have updated the code above.  The reflection is the one that I tried to avoid due to its poor method invocation performance.

Comment: Rule #2 of optimizing code: **Don't optimize prematurely.** This means, don't waste time optimizing code, and make the code more complicated, unless you *know* you have a performance issue. You may end up spending all you time tuning the wrong piece of code, and have no time left to fix the code that actually causes trouble. --- So, have you already established with a *profiler* that this is the code that needs to be tuned?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to iterate all the `run` methods using reflection, and look for an exact match of parameter types.

If you also need to support near matches, where Java coercion or some extended conversion is applied, then it's a bit more complicated, but still doable.

Once that's all working, you're done, unless a profiler says you have a performance issue in *this* code, in which case you might try to optimize to  search algorithm that's not sequential.